# What is adding entry lines to my package.json, and why?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

I have a npm package that I maintain. Something - perhaps npm itself - is adding entries to package.json. They start with an underscore character:

```
"_args": [
  [
    {
      "raw": "some-cool-package@https://registry.npmjs.org/some-cool-package/-/some-cool-package-2.2.0.tgz",
      "scope": null,
      "escapedName": "some-cool-package",
      "name": "some-cool-package",
      "rawSpec": "https://registry.npmjs.org/some-cool-package/-/some-cool-package-2.2.0.tgz",
      "spec": "https://registry.npmjs.org/some-cool-package/-/some-cool-package-2.2.0.tgz",
      "type": "remote"
    },
    "C:\\Users\\mike\\Documents\\mycompany"
  ]
],
"_from": "some-cool-package@>=2.2.0 <3.0.0",
"_id": "some-cool-package@2.2.0",
"_inCache": true,
"_location": "/some-cool-package",
"_phantomChildren": {},
"_requested": {
  "raw": "some-cool-package@https://registry.npmjs.org/some-cool-package/-/some-cool-package-2.2.0.tgz",
  "scope": null,
  "escapedName": "some-cool-package",
  "name": "some-cool-package",
  "rawSpec": "https://registry.npmjs.org/some-cool-package/-/some-cool-package-2.2.0.tgz",
  "spec": "https://registry.npmjs.org/some-cool-package/-/some-cool-package-2.2.0.tgz",
  "type": "remote"
},
"_requiredBy": [
  "/"
],
"_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/some-cool-package/-/some-cool-package-2.2.0.tgz",
"_shasum": "f0d5d982c15d63f653e48fff552400eb241b7407",
"_shrinkwrap": null,
"_spec": "some-cool-package@https://registry.npmjs.org/some-cool-package/-/some-cool-package-2.2.0.tgz",
"_where": "C:\\Users\\mike\\Documents\\mycompany",
```

**What is adding these entries?**

**Should I leave these entries on packages I publish to the public npm registry, or delete them?**

Comment: It looks like it could be [NPM itself](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10393)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're right, and that it's [NPM itself](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10393) putting absolute URLs into the `package.json` file.

It seems you're not the only one experiencing this issue, and that there seems to *be no plan to fix it either* (issue was closed on 15 Dec 2015), unfortunately.

Although one commenter recommended the [removeNPMAbsolutePaths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/removeNPMAbsolutePaths) package to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed in npm@5, if you update the publisher npm to npm@5 and re-publish packages, you'll notice that some of these additional entries are gone.

Comment: Thanks. Alas at least with npm 5.3.0 data loss issues prevent me from upgrading (any packages with `private: true` are destroyed by npm).